# Creating temporary table in postgresql with random name

Tags: postgresql, select, temp-tables

I use  this command to create a temporary table from a Select statement

```
Create TEMP Table myTable As Select * From Table1
```

I don't know how to do the same thing but assigning a random name instead of "myTable"
I have a function that create a random string, and i can assign the value to a variable but how can i use this variable as the name of my new temporary table ?

Thanks

Comment: how are you going to access the table with random name then?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you running this statement from a programming language? Or from  a postgres client?

Comment: You can create function in which you generate random string and use that string as a name of temp table inside postgresql function. Then you use it with select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL. To do so, the code must be part of a function or within a `do` block:

```sql
do $$
begin
EXECUTE format('Create TEMP Table %s As Select * From Table1',(select get_random_name()));
end $$;
```

It is of course your responsibility to record the temp table name so you can query it later...

That being said, let's note that the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) mentions

> Temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session, or
> optionally at the end of the current transaction

so maybe you can just use the same name all the time, as other clients (transaction) won't see temp tables creates by other other clients (transaction)

Comment: @Michele like for any other tables. You can ask a new question if you want.